# Call method in java for selenium test

Tags: java, selenium

i have a project in eclipse for selenium test.
my project contains Test.class and Utility.class

In my Utility.class i have a method like:

```
public static void UsernameElement(){
     try {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(Component._usernamef)).isDisplayed();
            System.out.println(" username field is displayed [TEST PASSED]");

        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("Username field is not displayed [TEST FAILED]");
        } finally {
            System.out.println("");
        }
 }
```

And then in my Test.class, i call the method like this:
Utility.UsernameElement();

Then i got this error:
"The method UsernameElement() is undefined for the type Utility"

i do not know i should put inside bracket in Utility.Username();
Can someone give a clue please. Thank you

Comment: Have you imported Utility class in your Test Class Java file?

Comment: i import like this import gsked.utility.Utility;

Comment: why is utility.Utility? is it under a package? can u share the structure screenshot?

Comment: Why a screenshot? Wouldn't the `package` and `import` statements be enough?

Comment: if those where right he shouldn't be facing this issue,i doubt if there is something else hence asked the structure ? do you have any clue what could be the issue?

Comment: yes i have a package named utility and inside this package i have a class named Utility which contains the class Username.